# Where to declare HTMLElementTagNameMap to get typings for Angular Elements?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-elements

I'd like to get accurate typings for my Angular elements, but where do I place the  `HTMLElementTagNameMap`-interface, so that is is recognized correctly?

Casting the type on every occurrence works:

```
const newCustomElement = 
   document.createElement('my-custom-element') as NgElement & WithProperties<{foo: 'bar'}>;
```

But using the second method mentioned on [Angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/elements#typings-for-custom-elements), by declaring a `HTMLElementTagNameMap` doesn't work for me.

How or where do I have to use this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create `typings.d.ts` file in `src` folder of your Angular CLI application:

```
type NgElement = import ('@angular/elements').NgElement;
type WithProperties<T> = import ('@angular/elements').WithProperties<T>;

interface HTMLElementTagNameMap {
  'my-custom-element': NgElement & WithProperties<{foo: 'bar'}>;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately just adding a `typings.d.ts` doesn't help (if it works, I should also have IntelliSense, right?).If I add it to the `tsconfig.json`, I get a bunch of errors, probably because I do it wrong.  
Could you please explain in more detail, how to use the `typings.d.ts` file?

Comment: Sadly it is still not working.
I made a [Stackbitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svadlw) to produce a minimal example.  
Though it doesn't work in Stackbitz, presumably because I can't set TS target to ES2015 and some polyfills are missing, but you could have a look at the code.

Comment: What if you remove import MyCustomElementComponent from typings.d.ts file?

Comment: I would not test d.ts file in stackblitz

Comment: Try using this typings.d.ts in VS cOde https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xujq2h?file=src/typings.d.ts. Note how I use your custom type through `type MyCustomElementComponent = import ('./app/my-custom-element/my-custom-element.component').MyCustomElementComponent;`

Comment: Of course not, the Stackbitz was only to share the code.  
Also with the new changes I have no success. Tried with a new project in Webstorm and VSCode. Does TS recognize the `typings.d.ts` automatically or do I have to do some sort of configuration?

Comment: If you have clear default Angular CLI project then it should work out of the box. If you changed tsconfig through `include`, `exclude` or `files` then it won't work. We need to have that typings.d.ts in scope of your tsconfig

Comment: No it's a plain Angular CLI project generated with `ng new`. I have no clue what's going wrong. Thank you very much for your help though.

Comment: I noticed that autocompletion only works in VS Code. I will create a small repo so you can test it in your environment

Comment: If you have time you can check this project https://github.com/alexzuza/angular-cli-global-ng-element-typings/blob/657f55e55217374e7cdf16332b968e1306421a51/src/app/app.component.ts#L12

Comment: I can confirm this works in VSCode, unfortunately not in Webstorm. Thank you very much for taking the time.

Comment: This works perfectly fine. But typings not identified in the template (HTML), any clue why is that?